# Convert CSV to LDIF for import into ldap?

Tags: csv, ldap, ldif

I have a MSSQL database with 13k users in a table with headers like username, password, fname, lname, etc.  I would love to be able to turn this data into a proper ldap server.

Currently I've done the following:  Create a job on the mssql server to export that table hourly in a csv.  The query pulls username, password, fname, lastname,and memberid. ftp this data hourly to my linux ldap server.

Can someone recommend a method on how to turn this csv into ldif so I can run ldapmodify and put in  all these entries into my ldap server? I'm assuming I can write a parser, but would love to know if there's already a product that can do csv to ldif conversion in this manner and if this plan makes any sense or if there's a better way to do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case someone is still looking for something like that, I made an autoit script to convert a given CSV file into LDIF:

```
;###########################################################################################
;##### Load requirements
#include <File.au3>

;###########################################################################################
;####       Start the app

LDIF_Converter()


;###########################################################################################
;####       App function
Func LDIF_Converter()
    TrayTip("CSV2LDIF Converter","Konvertierung gestartet...",2000,1)

    Local $file = "import_ADS.ldif", $contacts = 0, $sFilePath = "3CXImport.csv"
    ; Remote old file
    FileDelete($file);
    ; Write Header
    FileWrite($file,"#Base structure for each person");
    Filewrite($file,@crlf)
    FileWrite($file,"dn: ou=Telefonbuch,dc=example,dc=com");
    Filewrite($file,@crlf)
    FileWrite($file,"ou: Telefonbuch");
    Filewrite($file,@crlf)
    FileWrite($file,"objectClass: organizationalUnit");
    Filewrite($file,@crlf)
    FileWrite($file,"objectClass: top");
    Filewrite($file,@crlf)
    Filewrite($file,@crlf)

    ; Read out CSV File
    _FileReadToArray($sFilePath, $contacts, $FRTA_NOCOUNT, ";")

    ; Write to File for each contact
    For $i = 0 To UBound ($contacts) - 1
        ; Clear contact cache
        $cache = ""
        ; Write object ID & comman attributes
        $cache = $cache & "dn: uid="&$i+1&",ou=Telefonbuch,dc=example,dc=com" & @CRLF
        $cache = $cache & "objectClass: inetOrgPerson" & @CRLF
        $cache = $cache & "objectClass: organizationalPerson" & @CRLF
        $cache = $cache & "objectClass: person" & @CRLF
        $cache = $cache & "objectClass: top" & @CRLF

        ; Check if company or person and set the corresponding CN
        if $contacts[$i][1] == "" Then
            $cn = $contacts[$i][0]
        Else
            $cn = $contacts[$i][1] & " " & $contacts[$i][2]
        EndIf

        ; Write common name
        $cache = $cache & "cn: "&$cn & @CRLF
        if $contacts[$i][1] == "" Then
            $sn = $contacts[$i][0]
        Else
            $sn = $contacts[$i][1] & " " & $contacts[$i][2]
        EndIf

        ; Write lastname/company
        $cache = $cache & "sn: "&$sn & @CRLF

        ; Write mobile number
        $mobile = StringRegExpReplace($contacts[$i][5],'[a-zA-Z;\\/:.,*?\"<>|& ]',"")
        if $mobile <> "" And $mobile <> " " Then
            $cache = $cache & "mobile: "& $mobile & @CRLF
        EndIf

        ; Write organisation
        if $contacts[$i][0] <> "" Then
            $cache = $cache & "o: "&$contacts[$i][0] & @CRLF
        EndIf

        ; Write telephone number
        $phone = StringRegExpReplace($contacts[$i][3],'[a-zA-Z;\\/:.,*?\"<>|& ]',"")
        if $phone <> "" And $phone <> " " Then
            $cache = $cache & "telephoneNumber: "& $phone & @CRLF
        EndIf

        ; Write fax number
        $fax = StringRegExpReplace($contacts[$i][4],'[a-zA-Z;\\/:.,*?\"<>|& ]',"")
        if $fax <> "" And $fax <> " " Then
            $cache = $cache & "facsimileTelephoneNumber: "& $fax & @CRLF
        EndIf

        ; Write email
        if $contacts[$i][6] <> "" Then
            $cache = $cache & "mail: "&$contacts[$i][6] & @CRLF
        EndIf

        ; Seperator for contacts
        $cache = $cache & @CRLF
        ; Write all in one file access
        FileWrite($file,$cache)
    Next
    TrayTip("CSV2LDIF Converter","Konvertiertierung abgeschlossen ",2000)
    sleep(2000)
EndFunc
```

Answer (score -1):

A simple [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=csv+to+ldif) revealed several CSV to LDIF converters.

For example [scv2ldif2.pl](http://csv2ldif2.sourceforge.net/). It is in Perl, but you can find at least several Windows implementation of Perl (for example [Strawberry Perl](http://strawberryperl.com/).